# Regex for capturing value in an XML node.

Tags: regex

I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that can pull the value from a string that is formatted as XML, but is inside of a CDATA tag. The string looks like this:

```
<OAORNO>1234546qwerty</OAORNO><OBITNO>12345-qwerty</OBITNO><OBITDS>123456 qwerty</OBITDS>
```

The values could be digits, word characters, special characters, and spaces. Or any combination of those. So I am needing a one size fits all pattern.

I have a string split converter that accepts regular expressions as a parameter. The converter will split the sting based on the parameter you feed it, and return the string as an array. Which i will then display as a list.

however, i am having a time trying to create a one size fits all regular expression to suit my needs.

The closest pattern I've came up with is this:

```
(?<=\>)(.+)(?=\<)
```

But this captures everything between the first and last nodes. So from the example above it grabs everything between  and  so you end up with:

```
1234546qwerty</OAORNO><OBITNO>12345-qwerty</OBITNO><OBITDS>123456 qwerty
```

There has to be a way to do this, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You cannot abritrary XML reliably with Regex.  Is there a reason you cannot use a standard XML parser?

Comment: There's  limitations in the environment i'm working in that prevent me from using code behind.

Comment: You can access XML parsers in most templates, or you could do it client-side.  If you have regex available, you should be able to use a proper XML parser.  What framework are you using?

Comment: Are you familiar with Infor Smart office? It's using some version of .NET. I'm basically creating a presentation(called a "mashup"), and don't have a lot of options for code behind. I am able to create classes and package them in a .dll, that I can then reference in my XAML. Which is why i am able to use regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to your Regex converter, you can use a converter to take an XML Fragment and transform it to a `XElement`.  This will let you [bind to the XML Document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165615(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:XmlFragmentConverter x:Key="xElementConverter" />
</Grid.Resources>
<TextBox x:Name="xmlTb" Text="&lt;OAORNO&gt;1234546qwerty&lt;/OAORNO&gt;&lt;OBITNO&gt;12345-qwerty&lt;/OBITNO&gt;&lt;OBITDS&gt;123456 qwerty&lt;/OBITDS&gt;" Margin="10,10,322,286" Height="23" />

<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,38,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" 
            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=xmlTb, Path=Text, Converter={StaticResource xElementConverter}}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name,Mode=OneWay}" /><Run Text=": "/><Run Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,143,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" 
    DataContext="{Binding Text, Converter={StaticResource xElementConverter}, ElementName=xmlTb}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Elements[OBITNO]}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock><Run Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" /><Run Text=": "/><Run Text="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}" /></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Produces:

[image: Demo showing a binding to the xml data]

Converter:

```
sealed class XmlFragmentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var xmlString = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xmlString))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("value must be a string containing xml data", "value");
        }

        return XDocument.Parse("<root>" + xmlString + "</root>").Root;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` by default is greedy, which means that it will capturing as much as it can.  You can make it non-greedy so that it captures the shortest possible match by adding a `?` after it, like this: `(?<=\>)(.+?)(?=\<)`

However, there is another problem with your pattern.  The `.+?` will match anything, including an immediate `<` character, so when there is no text in an element, it captures too much.  Something like `(?<=\>)([^<]+?)(?=\<)` would be better in that case.